# Cmake Unix: Linker trouble - no -L added from target_link_libraries

Tags: linux, g++, makefile, cmake

I'm having some linker trouble on linux with my cmake project.

I've installed a package (nvidias Cg toolkit) which puts the library files in /usr/lib64

I use the find script here: http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/source/browse/branches/2.0/cmake/FindCg.cmake?r=452

If I print out CG_LIBRARY and CG_GL_LIBRARY with message() after running the find script they are both set to the correct file and path:
/usr/lib64/libCg.so-lpthread
/usr/lib64/libCgGL.so

The find script adds -lpthread to CG_LIBRARY. I've also tried removing the line where it adds this and add it manually to the target project.

Then I add these variables to the target project with target_link_libraries().

When I run make it says:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Now if I run make with VERBOSE=1 I can see that there is no -L/usr/lib64 entry. If I edit the CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/link.txt and add the entry manually it links it fine. Shouldn't cmake add the -L entries automaticaly with target_link_libraries()?
I've also tried using link_directories to add the -L manualy, but that doesn't do anything either..

Comment: hmmm ... was going to suggest try link_directories but you already have.

Comment: Yeah tried that.. my workaround for now is to add -L/usr/lib64 with target_link_libraries(<other libs here> -L/usr/lib64) . It seems like this might be a bug.. I've sent an email to the cmake mailing list so waiting to see what they are saying..